# If you lose the game and choose just...one...more...turn, how does the AI behave?

Tags: civilization-5, civilization-5-gods-and-kings

If one of the AI players beats you and you choose just one more turn, does the AI still try to win via domination or does it totally give up and do random things allowing you to dominate easily?

I am just wondering what to do in case of a victory condition loss other than domination. Does the AI still try to dominate after winning with one of the other victory conditions?

Comment: If I were the dev, I wouldn't go through the trouble of changing the AI's behaviour at all. But since I'm not, I really can't say for certain.

Comment: I'm 99% sure nothing changes and the game continues as if you haven't won or lost.

Comment: So, if nothing changes, does the AI go for the next available victory condition?

Answer (score 1):

This is a very conditional answer, but if the AI beats you with a Time Victory, what happens is that the option to choose "just one more turn" is disabled. [[Source 1](http://forums.civfanatics.com/showthread.php?t=383876), [Source 2]](http://forums.civfanatics.com/showthread.php?t=383985)

I haven't been able to find out what the AI does in the case of other victories though. There's a forum thread with the same question, but unfortunately it doesn't get very far:
  [How does the AI behave after somebody has won?](http://forums.civfanatics.com/showthread.php?t=478115)